# mysqli not found in Heroku Scheduler (but works on website)

Tags: mysql, heroku

I am trying to execute:

> heroku run ./php/bin/php www/scheduled.php

But I am getting the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'mysqli' not found in /app/www/scheduled.php
> on line 17

mysqli works when accessing the page directly in the browser.

I have set up my Heroku app following these instructions: https://gist.github.com/danielepolencic/6983030

Which recommend to add a php.ini file at the root with this content:

> extension_dir = "/app/www/ext/"
>
> extension=mysqli.so

Maybe this file is not being in the Scheduler?

What should I do to fix my issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any of those custom instructions anymore. Heroku has had a new, re-built version of the PHP support for months. Run `heroku config:unset BUILDPACK_URL` to stop using the multipack and get the latest version.

Delete that `Procfile`, `php.ini`, the `ext/` folder and `.buildpacks`.

Next, create a `composer.json` to enable `ext/gettext` (`ext/mysqli` is on by default):

```
{
  "require": {
    "ext-gettext": "*"
  }
}
```

Then you should be good to go. To run the scheduled process, simply do `heroku run php scheduled.php` (the app contents are no longer moved to a `www/` subdir upon push).

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/php for all docs; specifically, https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support on extensions, versions et cetera.